# How to use phpmailer and send mail as html from ckeditor

Tags: php, html, email, phpmailer

I'm use phpmailer to sending email, I have problems when inserting the contents of the html code on the form ckeditor, but data sent to the e-mail text only.

This is my code:

```
require_once ('class.phpmailer.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
if (isset($_POST['btn_send'])) 
    {

    $smtp_username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
    $smtp_password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
    $ssl_port = strip_tags($_POST['port']);
    $my_smtp = strip_tags($_POST['host']);
    $my_ssl = strip_tags($_POST['type']);
    $realname = strip_tags($_POST['realname']);
    $subject = strip_tags($_POST['subject']);
    $body = strip_tags($_POST['editor']);
    $emaillist = strip_tags($_POST['emaillist']); 


//...now get on with sending...
try 
{
//$mail->isSendmail();
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Body = ($body);
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "$my_ssl";
        $mail->Host = "$my_smtp";
        $mail->Port = "$ssl_port";
        $mail->AddAddress($emaillist);
        $mail->Username = "$smtp_username";
        $mail->Password = "$smtp_password";
        $mail->SetFrom("$smtp_username", "$realname");
        $mail->AddAddress($emaillist);
        $mail->epriority = "3";
        $mail->AddReplyTo("$smtp_username");
        $mail->Subject = "$subject";
        $mail->encode = ("yes");
        $mail->CharSet = "utf-8";
if($mail->Send())
{
$msg = "<div class='alert alert-success'>
Hi,<br /> bro mail terkirim ke ".$emaillist."
</div>";
}
}
catch(phpmailerException $ex)
{
$msg = "<div class='alert alert-warning'>".$ex->errorMessage()."</div>";
}}
```

I do not know what went wrong

Comment: as @Artem Ilchenko has mentioned, you need to enable *HTML* content delivery via `<PHPMailer object>.isHTML(true)` method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need edit this row
`$body = strip_tags($_POST['editor']);`
to `$body = $_POST['editor'];`

And add this line before mail send

`$mail->isHTML(true);`

Function strip_tags removes html markup.

But you need filter value another way.

Answer (score 0):

Please edit this line

```
$body = strip_tags($_POST['editor']); to $body = $_POST['editor'];
```

the strip_tags() function will remove all tags from your posted value. The you cant get the the html tags.

Please enable html in your PHP mailer by adding this line

```
$mail->isHTML(true);
```

So please edit the code and try this way.

This is working fine in my case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Codeigniter, you might face a problem if doing:

```
$body = $this->input->post('some_field_with_html_body');
```

You can fix it by doing:

```
$body = $_POST['some_field_with_html_body'];
```